# How to fetch data from REST api in flutter using .cer (certificate file )

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and i want to fetch data from server.But i need to use certificate file (.cer) while REST api call Like we do api call in android by using certificate file (.cer) . Can some one help me with this

Comment: Is your `cer` the client side certificate used for authentication? Or a pinned server cert?

Comment: Its pinned server certificate.